# Como usar dados da coluna de uma query como linha no datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Eu tenho uma consulta com 3 colunas que trazem dados do banco de dados Oracle e eu quero usar uma dessas colunas como linha no `datagridview`.

São  3 colunas `name`, `data` e `contagem de nomes`, e na coluna `Data` tem que ser uma linha no `datagrid` como se fosse `header` e abaixo vem o resto, como coluna.

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso em c#? Eu estou fazendo um aplicativo `winform`.

Fui claro? Se alguém não me entende, é só me avisar que eu tento explicar novamente.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Não se se entendi bem a sua pergunta, mas acredito que seria mais ou menos isso dentro de um laço de repetição para preencher a tabela:

```
var indexCabecalho = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
var indexPrimeiraColuna = 0;

dataGridView1[indexPrimeiraColuna, indexCabecalho].Value = "Data";

var index = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

dataGridView1[0, index].Value = "Name";
dataGridView1[1, index].Value = "Contagem";
```

Comment: Obrigado Richard,

Vou tentar construir aqui e caso dê certo eu aviso.